# Add cancellation token to an async task with progress

Tags: c#, async-await, task, cancellationtokensource, cancellation-token

I am using below code to do a time consuming operation in a WPF page async way along with progress reporting to the UI

```
    private void btnStart_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        txt_importStatus.Text = "";
        var progress = new Progress<string>(progress_info =>
        {
            //show import progress on a textfield
            txt_importStatus.Text = progress_info + Environment.NewLine + "Please dont close this window while the system processing the excel file contents";              
        });
        // DoProcessing is run on the thread pool.
        await Task.Run(() => DoProcessing(progress));
    }

    public void DoProcessing(IProgress<string> progress)
    {

        //read an excel file and foreach excel file row
        foreach(excelrow row in excelrowlist)
        {
            //do db entry and update UI the progress like 
            progress.Report("Processed x number of records. please wait..");    
        }  
    }
```

Now i would like to add an extra option of cancel this async operation in the middle .For doing so i found that i have to add below options

```
CancellationTokenSource tokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource();
CancellationToken token = tokenSource.Token;    
private void btnCacnel_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    tokenSource.Cancel();
}
```

But how can i pass this tokenSource to my DoProcessing call and how can i handle cancellation inside DoProcessing

Comment: On how to support cancellation, this may be helpful: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/parallel-programming/task-cancellation

Comment: Is `tokenSource` a class field?

Comment: Unrelated: I didn't find the resource quickly, but I read that MS recommends to always treat progress so it can be null. => `progress?.Report(...`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You actually don't need to pass the `CancellationTokenSource` to `DoProcessing`, but just the `CancellationToken`.

In order to handle the cancellation you could do something like this:

```
    public void DoProcessing(CancellationToken token, IProgress<string> progress)
    {
        //read an excel file and foreach excel file row
        foreach(excelrow row in excelrowlist)
        {
            if(token.IsCancellationRequested)
                break;

            //do db entry and update UI the progress like 
            progress.Report("Processed x number of records. please wait..");    
        }  
    }
```

In this case you'll need to create the cancellation token source already in `btnStart_Click`. In case it wasn't clear, you'd need to do like this:

```
    CancellationTokenSource tokenSource;

    private void btnStart_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        txt_importStatus.Text = "";
        var progress = new Progress<string>(progress_info =>
        {
            //show import progress on a textfield
            txt_importStatus.Text = progress_info + Environment.NewLine + "Please dont close this window while the system processing the excel file contents";              
        });
        // DoProcessing is run on the thread pool.
        tokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource();
        var token = tokenSource.Token;
        await Task.Run(() => DoProcessing(token, progress));
    }
```

Comment: Consider: What happens here, if the Start-Button is clicked two times, the second being before DoProcessing is done? And what does that mean for cancellation?

Comment: Yes this is a test case. How can we check the first job is still running ? Something like backgroundworker isbusy?

Comment: @JibinMathew You can create a variable "isRunning" that is set to true at the beginning of DoProcessing, and false at the end. In order to avoid what happens when pressing the start button twice, it depends on your use case. What I am used to do, is disable the button until the corresponding task has been finished or has been canceled.